# rails model attributes without corresponding column in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

I have some rails models which don't need any persistence, however I'd like rails to think the model actually has attributes x, y, z so when calling methods like to_json in the controller I get them included for free.

For example,

```
class ModelWithoutTableColumns << ActiveRecord::Base

def x
   return "Custom stuff here"
end
```

There is no column x in the database for Table "ModelWithoutTable" (sorry for the slightly confusing name!)

Anyone have an idea how to tackle this one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993839/how-to-iterate-activerecord-attributes-including-attr-accessor-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want ActiveModel. Check out http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/ for a great walkthrough by Yehuda Katz. Specifically the section called "Serialization" for your `to_json` requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base

Edit: Have you tried passing options to to_json, like :methods perhaps? See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001637)

Comment: Is it not possible to mix and match?

Comment: Well, you can obviously define whatever custom methods/attributes you want in any model -- they are just Ruby classes, after all. I inferred from your model name that you didn't want it to be DB-backed whatsoever :)

Comment: So you have some table attributes exposed automatically, and some defined purely by methods?

Comment: Thing is I've tried that and rails builtins like to_json don't recognize those methods (attr_accessor :x) as being part of the model 'table' attributes. Feels very un-intuitive, I think I am missing something obvious.

Comment: It seems like Rails is discriminating table attributes vs Ruby attributes . I was wondering if there is a Rails way of defining a Ruby attribute to be a 'proper' one?!

Answer (score 1):

That won't work--ActiveRecord::Base defines to_json, but requires a table.

You should check out the ActiveRecord::BaseWithoutTable plugin. [Here's how to use it](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/activerecord_base_without_table), and here's an [updated version for Rails 2](http://gitorious.org/projects/activerecord-basewithouttable-for-rails-2).

I haven't tried either of them, so no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out acts_without_database, the current details about it are [here](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2008/12/acts_without_database-using-activerecord-for-non-database-backed-objects/), but the site is down at the moment. [Here's the posting on RubyFlow](http://www.rubyflow.com/items/1442), it's from today.