# How do I validate a non-model form in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

Let's say I have a search form and I want to validate the length of the keyword. I want the form to highlight the invalid field (like model forms). I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find any useful information on validating non-model-backed forms in Rails 3. I've tried the *validatable* gem, but this doesn't seem to work with Rails 3:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Login:Class.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With Rails 3 you can extend "plain old Ruby objects" with some
ActiveModel extensions like Validations etc. ActiveRecord is extension of ActiveModel with DB support. Here is a very good Railscast describing it with easy example:

> In Rails 3 the non-database
>   functionality of Active Record is
>   extracted out into Active Model. This
>   allows you to cleanly add validations
>   and other features to tableless
>   models. http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Comment: Extending POROs would apply if the question wanted non-ActiveRecord forms... what about **non-model**, like a search form, or a couple fields letting a user pick a date range... anyone?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use tableless model. Check out here for more infomation: http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model