# Rails: How to validate data manually using a given model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am creating a Tumblr alternative to learn how use Rails. I am at the authentication part, and I decided to do it from scratch. I want to allow users to log in using either their username or their email. The user logs in via the Sessions controller but I need to verify if the login is either a valid username or a valid email. So I need to validate data in the Sessions controller using the User model.

I found this answer on SO: [How do I validate a non-model form in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118203/how-do-i-validate-a-non-model-form-in-rails-3) but it will force me to duplicate the validations. Is that the only way to do it, or is there another way that is cleaner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option I can imagine is creating a module and then including it at your User model and at the object you're going to use for the form:

```
module AuthenticationValidation
  def self.included( base )
    base.validates :username, :presence => true
    base.validates :email, :presence => true
    # add your other validations here
  end
end
```

And then include this module at your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AuthenticationValidation
end

class LoginForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion      
  include AuthenticationValidation

  attr_accessor :username, :email
end
```

And then you have avoided repeating the validation itself.