# Upload image with Paperclip Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip

**Client request a task:** Allow the Admin to change the site background image 


**Problem:** I don't want create new table for store only one image. now I want upload image with paperclip but not used database. Please suggest me a way for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create tableless model - there are already set of solutions, such as [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937429/activerecordbase-without-table-rails)