# Model without migration. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Comment model in my app with many comment_types

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment_type, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Also I have a public QA system. So for every pair I have a model

```
class QA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :question, :class_name => :comment, :as => :comment_type, :autosave => true
  has_one :asnwer,   :class_name => :comment, :as => :comment_type, :autosave => true
end
```

And this seems a little overuse for me to have a special table for QA model. Because this table should have only ID key. So is there a better solution? Or maybe something wrong with my architecture in total?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord::Base Without Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937429/activerecordbase-without-table)

Comment: seems like I've found a solution. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

Why a QA model? I would do with a Question has_many Answers and an question has_many Comments. And optionally you could say an Answer also has_many Comments, if you want users to be able to comment on other comments. Much easier I think.

Comment: The main feature (if it can be called so) of QA system in my app is to have only one question and one answer. So this solution is not for me, but thank you.