# How to iterate ActiveRecord Attributes, including attr_accessor methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've looked everywhere for an elegant solution.  The essential problem seems to be that ActiveRecord attributes that map to database columns are handled completely differently in ActiveRecord::Base than attr_accessor methods.

I would like to do something like:

```
model.attribute_names.each do |name|
  # do stuff
end
```

in a way that also includes attr_accessor fields, but not any other instance methods. I know this in not built-in, but what is the most elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really solve this. You can approximate a hack, but it's not something that will ever work nicely.

`model.attribute_names` should get you all the ActiveRecord ones, but the `attr_accessor` fields are not fields. They are just ordinary ruby methods, and the only way to get them is with `model.instance_methods`.

#### Idea 1

You could do `model.attribute_names + model.instance_methods`, but then you'd have to filter out all your other normal ruby methods `initialize, save`, etc which would be impractical.

To help filter the `instance_methods` you could match them up against `model.instance_variables` (you'd have to account for the `@` sign in the instance variables manually), but the problem with this is that instance variables don't actually exist at all until they are first assigned.

#### Idea 2

In your `environment.rb`, before *anything else ever* gets loaded, define your own `self.attr_accessor` in `ActiveRecord::Base`. This could then wrap the underlying `attr_accessor` but also save the attribute names to a private list. Then you'd be able to pull out of this list later on. However I'd advise against this... monkey-patching core language facilities like `attr_accessor` is guaranteed to bring you a lot of pain.

#### Idea 3

Define your own `custom_attr_accessor` in `ActiveRecord::Base`, which does the same thing as Idea 2, and use it in your code where you want to be able to retrieve the attribute names. This would be safe as you won't be clobbering the built-in `attr_accessor` method any more, but you'll have to change all your code to use `custom_attr_accessor` where neccessary

I guess in summary, what are you trying to do that needs to know about all the `attr_accessor` fields? Try look at your problem from a different angle if you can.

Comment: +1 thanks. I'm doing some stuff for handling of form fields.  Anyway, I completely agree about looking at things from different angles!  Since this question hasn't been asked/answered yet on SO, I thought it would be a good one to ask.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the attributes class / column type for generation of form fields. If the attribute has no value it is always nil.

Comment: You can also pass false to the instance_methods method and exclude inherited methods, narrowing it down even further: `model.instance_methods(false)`

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking to do the same thing, and found out it was the wrong approach altogether thanks to Orion's answer.

Incase anyone else's use case is similar to mine, here's my solution. I was using `attr_accessor` to add extra properties to the models after querying them from ActiveRecord. I then wanted to output the results as JSON etc.

A better solution is to first convert the Models from ActiveRecord into regular hashes, and then add the `attr_accessor` properties as regular hash keys.

Example:

```
model_hash = model_from_activerecord.attributes.to_options
model_hash[:key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with for myself builds upon Orion Edwards' answer.

**The code:**

`klass_attributes = klass.column_names + klass.instance_methods(false).
  map(&:to_s).keep_if{|a| a.include?('=')}.map{|a| a.sub('=', '')}`

**The breakdown:**

`klass.instance_methods(false)` brings back only instance methods, and not inherited methods.

`map(&:to_s)` converts the array of symbols into an array of strings so we can use the `include?` method. Also needed to merge with array of strings returned by column_names.

`keep_if{|a| a.include?('=')}` will remove all strings within the array that do not have an equals sign. This was important, since I noticed that attr_accessor attributes all had '='. Ex: 'app_url' vs 'login_url='

`map{|a| a.sub('=', '')}` is the final piece that then removes the '=' from each string in the array.

You end up with an array of strings that represent attributes, including attr_accessor attributes.