# how to access attr_accessor in rails model using `attribute_names` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to access attribute names of a model but it is not showing all of them.

I have User model and I added a `attr_accessor :color` in it (since I don't want to store this on my database as column).
But if I try to access attribute names using `User.first.attribute_names` it is showing only database columns,it is not showing 'color' attribute,so how do I access all the attributes ?is there any methods which list attr_accessor as attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you don't know difference b/w attr_acessabe and attr_accessor look at

[How to iterate ActiveRecord Attributes, including attr_accessor methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993839/how-to-iterate-activerecord-attributes-including-attr-accessor-methods)

you can add attr_accessor if you don't an attribute to save in database then add that att_accessor to attr_accessable :)

```
attr_accessor :color
attr_accessible :color
```

now

```
User.accessible_attributes # => ["color"], but beware that you have lost all other attribute you need to add those too if you want to enable mass assignment. 

    attr_accessible :color,:first_name,:blah,:blah...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
User.accessible_attributes #will return array of accessible attributes
```

Comment: it is returning nil,I am using rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8 is that a problem ?

Comment: oh, i missed this while reading question. accessible_attributes will return all attr_accessable not att_accessor.posting another answer as in text in comment can't be formatted

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried #methods i.e. User.first.methods or perhaps User.accessible_attributes is more in line with what your looking for.