# How do you output all attributes including attr_accessor attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attr-accessor

Let's say I have a user class with columns name and email:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :gender
end

user = User.new(:gender => 'male', :name => 'joe', :email => 'user@example.com')
```

If I want the attributes I usually can do user.attributes, or user.inspect, or user.to_yaml.
However this does not output the gender.  Is there a way I can easily output everything?

Comment: Very similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993839/how-to-iterate-activerecord-attributes-including-attr-accessor-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it what you're trying to do is easily possible to do.

See this question:

[How to iterate ActiveRecord Attributes, including attr_accessor methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993839/how-to-iterate-activerecord-attributes-including-attr-accessor-method)

Comment: thanks, you are a master of search.  I couldn't find a previous question posted for this.  I guess I'll just have to hand code all the attr_accessor fields.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Sorry I wasn't able to locate a more specific solution for you. I learned something here as well, so thanks. Would you mind accepting the answer at some point?