# Uknown attributes error nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting an unknown attributes error, though I have tried some of the similar answers to this question here.  I am trying to update council and property attributes into a join table council history using a nested form, when I try to load the view form I get this error  please advice what you think I might be doing wrong am new to rails and programming.

**Error**

```
Started PUT "/properties/6/build/council" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-19 17:35:45 +0100
Processing by Properties::BuildController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"wBWQaxtBioqzGLkhUrstqS+cFD/xvEutXnJ0jWNtSa0=", "property"=>   {"council_history_attributes"=>{"council_id"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Create Council history",  "property_id"=>"6", "id"=>"council"}
  Property Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" =  ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "6"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute: council_history_attributes:
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:88:in `block in  assign_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:216:in `block in update_attributes'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:in `update_attributes'
  app/controllers/properties/build_controller.rb:24:in `update'
```

**Property Model**

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :address_attributes, :tenants_attributes, :meter_attributes, :council_history, :council_history_attributes, :property_id, :council_id, :status
  belongs_to :user 

  has_one :council_history

  has_one :council, through: :council_history, :foreign_key => :council_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :council

end
```

**Council Model**

```
class Council < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :CouncilEmail, :name, :CouncilTel

  has_many   :council_history

  has_many   :properties, :through => :council_history, :foreign_key => :property_id
end
```

**Council History Model**  -- **Join Table**

```
class CouncilHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :council_id, :property_id, :vacant 

  belongs_to :council

  belongs_to :property

end
```

**View **

```
<%= simple_form_for @property, :url => url_for(:action => 'update', :controller =>    'properties/build'), :method => 'put' do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :council do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.input :council_id, :collection => Council.all  %>
      <%= builder.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Property/build Controller**

```
class Properties::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

   steps :tenant, :meter, :council, :confirmed 

  def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @tenants = @property.tenants.new(params[:tenant_id])
    @meter = @property.build_meter
    @council = @property.build_council
    @council_history = @property.council_history.build
    render_wizard
  end

  def edit
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  end


  def update
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    params[:property][:status] = step.to_s
    params[:property][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @property.update_attributes(params[:property])
    render_wizard @property
  end
```

Comment: Put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :council_history` in your `Council` model.

Comment: That didn't work, still got the same error.

Comment: Sorry, try putting it into your `Property` model, as that's the controller that gave the error.

Comment: Thanks @mbratch that worked, but now I am getting a mass assignment error for councils even though I put it in the attr accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### in property.rb

add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :council_history`

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible  :name, :address_attributes, :tenants_attributes, :meter_attributes,         :council_history, :council_history_attributes, :property_id, :council_id, :status
 belongs_to :user 

 has_one :council_history

  has_one :council, through: :council_history, :foreign_key => :council_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :council
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :council_history #add this line

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer [Muntasim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540887/muntasim). 
I can't comment directly on the accepted answer but, wanted to update how to do this now that attr_accessible is no longer in Rails (last version v2.3.8) with the introduction of **[strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)** in Rails 4+.

Strong parameters in controllers,

```
def person_params
  params.permit(:name, {:emails => []}, :friends => [ :name, { :family => [ :name ], :hobbies => [] }])
end
```

Strong parameters can be used [outside of controllers](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#use-outside-of-controllers) (this is the issue that I was running into that led me here),

```
raw_parameters = { :email => "john@example.com", :name => "John", :admin => true }
parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(raw_parameters)
user = User.create(parameters.permit(:name, :email))
```

Alternatively if you want to use attr_accessible, you still can, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993839/how-to-iterate-activerecord-attributes-including-attr-accessor-methods#993859).

> If you want to use attr_accessible, you need to add
>   protected_attributes to your Gemfile. Otherwise, you will be faced
>   with a RuntimeError.